# blackletter1 and yfrak

Tags: fonts

A follow-up to my earlier [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196728/text-fraktur-at-8pt). I have implemented `\textfraktone` using the `blackletter1` fonts and the T1 encoding, but I get different results to that from using the `\textfrak` from the `yfonts` package: specifically the final "s".
I think `\textfraktone` is correct (as one should not use a "medial s" at the end of a word), is this a bug in `\textfrak`?  A minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{yfonts}
\newcommand{\textfraktone}[1]{{\fontfamily{yfrak}\selectfont #1}}
\begin{document}
With \verb|\textfrak|: \textfrak{Greis},  
with \verb|\textfraktone|: \textfraktone{Greis}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think I found the issue, one gets the "correct" final s in `yfonts` by using `\textfrak{Greis:}`, so the `blacklettert1` package is a bit more "automatic".

Comment: On the other hand, you have to type `\textfraktone{Aus\/gang}` if you want the final s.